# ios10 swift3.0 Alamofire upload picture gets an error

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Here is my Code. I want to upload an image using Alamofire

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let imagePost = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let image = imagePost
        // transform image into NSData
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
        // Home path
        let homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory()
        let documentPath = homeDirectory + "/Documents"

        let fileManager: FileManager = FileManager.default

        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: documentPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        catch let error {
            print (error)
        }
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: documentPath.appending("/image.png"), contents: data, attributes: nil)
        let filePath: String = String(format: "%@%@", documentPath, "/image.png")
        print("filePath:" + filePath)
        // Alamofire upload
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(filePath.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "head_picture")
        }, to: URL, encodingCompletion: { response in
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print(response)
            switch response {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                        print("Success")
                        print(response)
                        print("Success")
                        self.portraitUIImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    })
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("error")
                print(encodingError)
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        print ("有错误")
    }
}
```

I print my request like this, the part of url is hidden

```
> success(request: $ curl -i \
-X POST \
-b "JSESSIONID=B4148AC39E35C599773A9A86DAE8D19F" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=alamofire.boundary.74e3ed8f93ce9353" \
-H "Accept-Language: zh-Hans-US;q=1.0, en;q=0.9" \
-H "User-Agent: OldFriend/1.0 (MichaelHuang.OldFriend; build:1; iOS 10.3.0) Alamofire/4.4.0" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
"http://***.**.***.200:9999/upload/head-picture.do", streamingFromDisk: false, streamFileURL: nil)
```

I want to upload head picture to my server using Alamofire4.0. Now I get an error like this. I get the message from my server saying I need to provide MultipartFile parameter 'head_picture'. But I did provide it, how can I fix it ?

> success
>   SUCCESS: HTTP Status 400 – Bad Requesth1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}
>
> ## HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
>
> **Type** Status Report
>
> **Message** Required MultipartFile parameter 'head_picture' is not present
>
> **Description** The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M18
>
> success

Comment: test your api in POSTMAN first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vinod Kumar, I used the code provided by him

Here is the code, and part of url is hidden

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let imagePost = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            // 修正图片的位置
            let image = self.fixOrientation(aImage: imagePost)
            // 把图片转成NSData
            let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
            // Home目录
            let homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory()
            let documentPath = homeDirectory + "/Documents"
            //文件管理器
            let fileManager: FileManager = FileManager.default
            //把刚刚图片转换的data对象拷贝至沙盒中 并保存为image.png
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: documentPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }
            catch let error {
                print (error)
            }
            fileManager.createFile(atPath: documentPath.appending("/image.png"), contents: data, attributes: nil)
            let filePath: String = String(format: "%@%@", documentPath, "/image.png")

            print("filePath:" + filePath)
            // Alamofire upload
            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                multipartFormData.append(data!, withName: "head_picture", fileName: "my.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }, to:"http://*******.200:9999/upload/head-picture.do")
            { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
                    })

                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                          print(response.request)  // original URL request
                        print(response.response) // URL response
                        print(response.data)     // server data
                        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                        //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
                        if let JSON = response.result.value {
                            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                        }
                    }
                    self.portraitUIImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print ("有错误")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i've uploaded images successfully with Alamofire, and I do quite differently:

change this code:

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(filePath.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "head_picture")
    }, to: URL, encodingCompletion: { response in
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print(response)
        switch response {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                    print("Success")
                    print(response)
                    print("Success")
                    self.portraitUIImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                })
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("error")
            print(encodingError)
        }
    })
```

to like this:

```
    let req = Alamofire.upload(data, to: URL, method: HTTPMethod.put, headers: nil)
    req.response { (response: DefaultDataResponse) in
        print(response)
    }
```

You can try with another method like `post`, and send headers if need.
Hope it'll help you.